# Changing text box content on a VB.net form from a class

Tags: vb.net, winforms

This seems like a trivial problem but I just can't get it to work and have spent the last 30 minutes going round in circles :-(

I've got a form with a text box on it and an object handler which is located in a separate class.  I'd like to update the content of the text box with the output from the object handler.

I'm trying to access it this way:

```
formName.textBoxName.Text = value
```

but nothing happens.  I can, however, read the status of buttons on the same form so I'm confused.  It appears that I can access some of the form controls from my class but only read only ?

I know I'm getting output from my class because I can view it in the debug window.

I've tried changing the modifier property of the text box with no difference - I'm sure that it's a dumb mistake that I've made but I just can't see it.

How can I change my textBox value from another class ?

Here's my code:

Class: Summarizer.vb

```
If frm_Settings.btn_NextSection.Enabled = True Then
    Console.WriteLine("Boo!")
    frm_Settings.txt_NextSection.Text = "Boo!"
End If
```

Form: frm_Settings consists of (amongst other things) a text box txt_NextSection and a button btn_NextSection.  The value of the button is being read correctly but the textbox content cannot be set.

thanks in advance

Comment: Are you sure that the `formName` instance is referencing the form that you expect to change? Or are you just using the class name?

Comment: It's definitely the form name.  I'm using the same name to read the state of a button on the same form and that works fine.

Comment: I have not explained well. When your 'object handler' tries to update the textbox it needs the instance of the form that contains the textbox, not simply its name. When you have created the form, somewhere there was a `Dim f As MyForm = new MyForm()`. You need to use the variable f that references a live instance of MyForm. Not simply MyForm.TextBox.Text

Comment: The form isn't created dynamically - I added it to my VB project at design time so I guess somehow I've got to find that handle via code ?

Comment: That handle is the `Me` keyword that represents the current instance of your form. You should pass it to the class that contains your object handler (Use a parameter constructor or set via it a class property or pass it directly to the handler, can't be more precise without seeing your code, if you add the code that calls the class I could try to give an answer with an example)

Comment: Thanks for your help Steve, I've just added the code.  As you can see it's really simple ...

Comment: This May be quoting the obvious, but make sure your text box is ENABLED and  also that it is NOT READONLY

Comment: @Zak I checked those already and they are correct.  Googling throws up some unbelievable complicated solutions to this and none of them exactly fit the problem in hand which, on the face of it, seems to simple.

Comment: Does the Summarizer class implement the form? or does the form implement the Summarizer class? What is the output from the object handler? Maybe you could replace the object handler output with a function so it simply returns the data you need back to the form? Your code is okay it ought to set the text in the form so possibly your issue lies elsewhere but its difficult to say without looking at the relavant summarizer object handler class code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will try to give an answer, but many things are still unclear.
When executing the code of `frm_Settings` you, *probably*, declare and initialize an instance of the class `Summarizer`.
At that point pass, to the constructor of the class, a reference to the current instance of `frm_Settings`

```
....
Dim sz = new Summarizer(Me)
sz.ExecuteSomeMethod()
.....
```

Now, add a constructor for the class `Summarizer` in this way

```
Public Class Summarizer

   ' This is the local reference to the frm_Setting instance passed in the constructor'
   Dim callerInstance As frm_Settings

   ' This constructor receives the instance of the frm_Settings class 
   'that has created the instance of Summarizer'
   Public Sub New(ByVal caller As frm_Settings)
       ' Set the local reference to the instance passed in'
       callerInstance = caller
   End Sub 

   .....

End Class
```

now, in your handler that needs to update the textbox, the code could be changed to

```
' Use the instance of the frm_Settings that has created the instance of this class'
If callerInstance.btn_NextSection.Enabled = True Then
    Console.WriteLine("Boo!")
    callerInstance.txt_NextSection.Text = "Boo!"
End If
```

Comment: Thanks for that Steve, it almost works.  What I overlooked (and this may be why my original code didn't work) is that I'm running the Summarizer class in one thread and the form in another.  VB shows an error and gives guidance on how to fix this which I'm working through now.  I'll update later ...

Comment: Steve, your code, combined with this here (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171728.aspx) to get around the threading problem worked a treat.  Thank you very much !